# Установить line-height равный размеру шрифта

Tags: html, css

Необходимо уменьшить высоту линии в строке. У меня получается только так (слева как надо, справа мое):

[image]

Т.е. высота перестает уменьшаться при 16px. Все что меньше не влияет на текст.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="article-title small">Теперь новая некая услуга переведена в электронный вид</a>
```

CSS (все что влияет на отображение ссылки)

```
.small {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*[class*="title"].small {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.short-article-list li .article-title {
    color: #787878;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin: 0px 0;
}

.short-article-list.another-view li a {
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

Comment: мне кажется эти размеры зависят от doctype. у меня используется <!DOCTYPE html>, а если использовать переходный то все ок <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я, наверное, не совсем понял что вам нужно, но междустрочный интервал можно изменять относительно исходной ширины в процентах (1% = 0.01), то есть:

```
.short-article-list.another-view li a {
    line-height: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: такое не работает, пробовал разные единицы измерения. все что меньше 100% или меньше 1 или меньше 16px не работает

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/d6bfywxk
пришлите код списка, видимо что-то с ним не то, а лучше рабочий кусок, чтобы можно было вставить и посмотреть своими глазами, так всем будет легче помочь вам.

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/osm6prfk

Comment: еще вопрос по шрифту. почему то в фотошопе и на странице один и тот же шрифт отображается с разными отступами между букв. в результате размеры не сходятся с макетом (пробовал уменьшить межбуквенный интервал, ничего хорошего не вышло, т.е. получается намного меньше макетного). это вообще реально сверстать пиксель в пиксель с макетом или допускаются такие погрешности с шрифтами?

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/7wvqb3zg

Comment: какой шрифт используете?

Comment: я понял в чем проблема, но можно ли при моем доктайпе изменить высоту строки?

Comment: Хм, не ожидал такого поведения от доктайпа.
Насчет шрифтов возможно, просто в фотошопе размер указывается в пунктах. Измените в настройках "Единицы измерения.." на пиксели. Тут картинка\макет, сверху красным цветом наложил текст через html, на кегель не смотрите, размеры соответствуют: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwe61v7yovftaW5vRjh5Z0U4REE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы настало счастье сделайте ссылку блочным элементом.

```
.short-article-list.another-view li a {
    line-height: 13px;
    display: block;
}
```

Ну а сверху уж сами отодвинете. http://cssdeck.com/labs/b6qbxfkt